# Algebra I: "Any ordered ring must contain at least 5 elements"

Tags: abstract-algebra

Okay the introduction of the question says

The field of four elements. Consider the following multiplication and addition tables on the set $R= \{x, y, a, b\}$

so there are two tables that show the relationship among all the elements. And I found out that $x= 0, y= 1, a= 0, b= 1$.

(b) Define an ordered ring

Okay I got this question

(c) Extend part (b) to show that any ordered ring must contain at lest 5 elements. Is the number 5 important here?

k so for (c), I need to show that any ordered ring needs more than 4 elements (at least 5).
So.. I think the questions is saying elements are not specified but just in general.

How do i prove this? so 0, 1, -1 and I don't know where to start this question.

Comment: Hint: Could it be finite?

Comment: The trivial ring $\{0\}$ is trivially an ordered ring, so you must specify that your ring has at least two elements.

Comment: @TedShifrin
Yes it is finite.

Comment: @Dafty: I think Ted is gently hinting that an ordered ring *can't* be finite.

Comment: @TedShifrin please dont be frustrated. I am frustrated trying to understand all the things you guys have talked about.

I gave you an up vote as well. Ty

Comment: @Dafty: I didn't get the impression he was frustrated with *you*.

Comment: No, no, not with you, @Dafty. With the site. When I looked at Matemáticos's profile, I wasn't upset at him, either,and removed my snarky comment.

Comment: @TedShifrin hahaha :) :) :)

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas: rings are in many cases tacitly assumed to be unital and commutative, with $0\neq 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number $5$ is not special: in fact if your ordered ring is not trivial (that is $R\ne0$) then $R$ is infinite: because if $a\in R$ with $a\ne0$, then either $a>0$ or $a<0$, which implies that all the elements $na$ with $n\in\mathbb Z^+$ are distinct. Here $na:=\underbrace{a+a+\cdots+a}_{n\ \style{font-family:inherit;}{\text{times}}}$, and the sequence $(na)_{n\geq1}$ will be strictly increasing or strictly decreasing, according with $a>0$ or $a<0$, respectively.

Comment: Okay so since ***na*** will be strictly increasing or strictly decreasing, ***R*** is infinite.

so that shows that "at least 5" is not important, is that correct?

like "at least 5" is not meaningful since ***R*** is infinite.

Comment: @Dafty Exactly. You can change "$5$" by any positive integer (for example the ominous "1984" ;-) )

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Define $n=\overbrace{1+\dots+1}^{n\text{ times}}$ and compare $n$ with $n+1$.

Comment: The ring is not necessarily unital.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas That depends on a convention. For many authors, "ring" means unital ring (and if they want to refer to a ring without unit, they often say "rng"). See for example Jacobson's Algebra books.

Comment: @user43208 thanks. So how do i show that any ordered ring needs more than 4 elements?

Comment: Well, fortunately (or unfortunately, as the case may be), Matematicos Chibchas has shown you how to do it. But you could ignore his answer and take the present hint, together with the fact that you know the unit 1 is positive (one of the axioms of an ordered ring).

Comment: @user43208 I mean so far his answer seems most convincing to me.

but k i know that unit 1 is positive -> so what can i tell from that?

Comment: @Dafty: we have $0 < 1$, right? Look carefully at the axioms for an ordered ring, and see what else you can derive from that. You may want to invoke transitivity and asymmetry of the order at some point.

Comment: @user43208 okay so 0,1 right. transitivity a<b & b<c then ***a<c***
okay i got that so three elements right?

my professor hasn't taught us about asymmetry yet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10576/discussion-between-dafty-and-user43208)

Comment: Sorry, Dafty -- I decline. But think about it, and good luck!

Comment: @user43208 it's all good. ty for the help bro. take care!